# CSS3 Modal Box covers up content after it?

Tags: html, css, modal-window

So I have no idea why it would cover it up but then when i go to sign out you see it displayed but in the background.  It will only show when i pull up the sign out modal window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SVHS Library Sign In/Out</title>
    <meta name="SVHS-sign_in/out v1.0" content="form">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/modal.css">
    <style>
        body {
            width: 700px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Sign In/Out</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- SIGN IN MODAL ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <a href="#openModal1">Sign In</a>

    <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <p>
                Please fill out and click sign in.
            </p>
            <form action=".php" method="post" class="">
                First Name: 
                <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="check in/out book">Check In/Out Book<br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="use computer">Use Computer<br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="other">Other<br>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SIGN OUT MODAL -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <a href="#openModal2">Sign Out</a>

    <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <p>
                Please fill out and click sign out.
            </p>
            <form action=".php" method="post" class="">
                First Name: 
                <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Out">
            </form>
        </div>

    <!-- FOOTER --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <footer>
        <nav class="nav_footer">
        </nav>
        <div class="legal">
            <p> 
                This is the footer.
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

===============CSS======================
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    }
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: Covering what.. Please edit your question and explain your problem briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your are talking about footer display..

Its just because your signout modal's div is not closed completely.. So Footer will appear when Signout modal appears..

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qpDSU/1/)**

and here is what u need to change:

```
<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <p>
            Please fill out and click sign out.
        </p>
        <form action=".php" method="post" class="">
            First Name: 
            <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out">
        </form>
    </div>
                </div>
```

Jus add one more div at the end as I have shown above...